# How to exhaustively replace all regex matches?

Tags: regex, match

Is it possible to write a regex pattern so that all matches are exhaustively replaced, without resorting to running the regex multiples times, or using extra libraries like Perl's `Regexp::Exhaustive`, Ruby's `string.scan(/regex/)`, etc (the language is not important to this question)?

For example, let's say I need to replace a dash `-` with `\-/` to allow proper hyphenation for compound words in a LaTeX document.

My regex so far would be (PCRE):

```
s/(\w+)-(\w+)/$1\\-\/$2/ig;
```

In this admittedly artificial example, it will only replace the first dash.

```
six-nation-golden-cup-award
```

will become

```
six\-/nation-golden-cup-award
```

Is there a better regex to have it replace all occurences, so that one gets:

```
six\-/nation\-/golden\-/cup\-/award
```

Comment: why not simplr replace `-` by `\-/`

Comment: I do not understand your comment? Isn't what the regex is doing at the moment? But it replaces the first occurrence only.

Comment: @gsl I think he means "Why not write `s/-/\\-\//g`?"

Comment: You don't need a regex if you want to replace a static term by another static term. Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I see. That would not work, since the dash `-` could be used in other cases along the text, where it should not become `\-/`. Let me reword the question. Thanks!

Comment: @hek2mgl I know, my question is more about knowing more of regex, specificcally in if such a feature as Exhaustive replacing exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current regex is overly complicated, it matches the entire strings around the dash. I would do this:

```
\b-\b
```

[Regex101 demo with substitution](https://regex101.com/r/tY2zJ1/1)

`\b` means *"word-boundary"*, so it requires that a word starts or ends there. You can see from the Regex101 link that not every dash is matched. In regexes, "word" characters include numbers and underscores `_`, so with this a string like `4-_` would be found and replaced with `4\-/_`.

If you do the [lookbehind and lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) manually, you can define the [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) yourself. So this:

```
(?<=[a-z])-(?=[a-z])
```

Would require the preceding/following character to be letters only, no numbers/underscores.

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/iL4tL9/1)

Comment: Thank you, I knew about `\b` but I was thinking of more complex usage. This is so simple and elegant. Thanks!

Comment: You could do the lookbehind/lookahead manually to have more control over which characters you do and don't accept. Is `4-_` acceptable? The current answer would match it, but `(?<=[a-z])-(?=[a-z])` would require the preceding/following character are letters only, no numbers/underscores.

Comment: No, `4-_` would not be acceptable. Thank you for adding more details, very instructive.